# UIThread , can't access my UI elements

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, user-interface

I m developing a coverflow with android-coverflow http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Items are loaded form a WebService, so I load the date in a separate thread like this:

```
//(in MyActivityClass onCreate) 

coverFlow1 = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow); // coverFlow1 is class member 

new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                MyWebServiceClass.getInstance().getCoverFlowData();

                MyActivityClass.this.runOnUiThread(
                        new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {

                                        MyActivityClass.getInstance().loadItems();
                            }
                });

            }
          }).start();
```

The problem is that coverFlow1 isnt available inside the loadItems method (it s null , even if I load it again with : coverFlow1 = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);

Maybe I ve done a bad usage of runOnUiThread ( I m new to Android development) ?

Comment: use `MyActivityClass.this.loadItems();` instead `MyActivityClass.getInstance().loadItems();` in `run` of `Runnable`

Comment: use lazy loading in android and update the adapter using async task or handler to reflect changes in gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that coverFlow1 isnt available inside the loadItems
>   method

Just add `coverFlow1` as parameter of your method, isn't?

```
MyActivityClass.getInstance().loadItems(CoverFlow flow);
```

Also you should call it as `MyActivityClass.this.loadItems(CoverFlow flow);`

`getInstance()` there is no reason and you really don't need and it's incorrect.

Comment: It s ok now with BonsPlansActivity.this.reloadOffers(coverFlow1); thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call `MyWebServiceClass.getInstance().getCoverFlowData();` you are trying to get static reference which is not correct. You need this exact running activity, so you have to add `this` to it. So it should look like this `MyWebServiceClass.this.getCoverFlowData();`.

Do this to your `MyActivityClass.getInstance().loadItems();` method too

Comment: MyWebServiceClass is not extended from Activity. ok for MyActivityClass , thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Coverflow extends gallary. So you can create an adapter class to load the data.

Set this adapter as the adapter of this coverflow.